# Could not initialize Applet Error

Tags: java

I have installed java version 1.7 on my ubuntu pc . I have latest iced tea web plugin installed on my firefox . I have installed java3d 1.5.2 api . I have set paths for both java and java-3d . Still when I click http://ccnsb06-iiith.vlabs.ac.in/exp2/ve_exp2.html which has an applet runs based on java 3d api, it is giving an error

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B41p1ExqjUEOM3hjdUNwNjBldXc/view?usp=sharing

P.S : I have same problem with my CentOs 6 machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry , Every one the problem is with development team , no problem with software initalization